# How to connect to an SQL Server from VBA in Excel?

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, odbc, export-to-excel

I need to download some data from a database (Microsoft Windows Server 2012, SQL Server 2012) into Excel (Windows 11, Office 2016). If it was a one-time data dump I'd just use Data -> Get Data -> From Database and use the resulting sheet. But the end user will need to pass a different parameter to the query every time, and I don't want to confuse any non-IT people with having to see and modify an SQL query. So, I tried VBA. The plan is to take some parameters from input cells.

The ODBC data source administrator shows that the following drivers are already installed for the SQL server: Microsoft Access dBase Driver, Microsoft Access Driver, Microsoft Access Text Driver, Microsoft Excel Driver, SQL Server, SQL Server Native Client 10.0 and 11.0.

In Excel, I successfully added the Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library. Connection data type is available and doesn't throw a type error.

My subroutine, with dummy data in the connection string:

```
Sub Compute()
  Dim ConnectionString As String
  ConnectionString = "Server=00.00.00.00;Database=MyDatabase;User ID=MyName;Password=MyPassword"
  Dim Connection As ADODB.Connection `Also tried Connection without ADODB.
  Set Connection = New Connection
  Connection.Open ConnectionString
End Sub
```

I get "Data source name not found and no default driver specified." error from ODBC driver manager.

Is VBA the right tool for what I need to do or is there a better way to conveniently re-run the query with fresh parameters and re-fill the result cells without exposing the end user to any SQL?

How can I fix this error? Some additional SQL server driver? A different VBA library? A different connection string? All of the above?

Comment: Add `DRIVER={SQL Server};` before `Server=`. Aternatively use ODBC driver manager to create a DSN and then use `Connection.Open DSNname`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried recording you creating a new connection with the database? It shows you how the connectionstring is supposed to be looking like. There will be a bit of unneeded info as you often have with recording a macro but it helps me out a bunch with these type of things.

Maybe your connection issue is because you set it to a New Connection instead of

> Dim connection As ADODB.connection
> Set connection = New ADODB.connection

Like shown here [how-to-connect-to-microsoft-sql-server-using-vba](https://simpleexcelvba.com/how-to-connect-to-microsoft-sql-server-using-vba/)
The first introduction I had to refreshing a connection was something like this:

```
Sub McrPricePerSupplRefresh()
    Dim Suppl As String
    
    Suppl = InputBox("Which supplier (code)?")
    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("SupplierPrices").ODBCConnection
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .CommandText = Array( _
        "SELECT * FROM WORSTDATABASE.PUB.""peoplemadethiswithdashes-veryannoying"" "WHERE ""peoplemadethiswithdashes-veryannoying"".""supplier-code""='" & Suppl & "'")
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .Connection = "ODBC;DSN=ourERP;UID=MYNAME;HOST=OURHOST;PORT=2007;DB=WORSTDATABASE;PWD=NONYA"
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = True
        .SavePassword = False
        .SourceConnectionFile = ""
        .SourceDataFile = ""
        .ServerCredentialsMethod = xlCredentialsMethodIntegrated
        .AlwaysUseConnectionFile = False
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("SupplierPrices").Refresh
End Sub
```

Which has been edited a *tad* bit ofc and isn't a ADODB connection as you mentioned but it shows how to adjust the query based on user-input/variables (or from cells or what have you).
If it's not a simple refresh, only look at the SQL of my code then.

Hope this helps!